# Present Perfect vs Simple Past

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

Can an American English speaker confirm whether the Simple Past tense is possible in the following sentences?

- I didn't have so much fun for a long time.
- You don't need to call him. He lost his phone.

I believe only the Present Perfect tense is possible here in British English:

- I haven't had so much fun for a long time.
- You don't need to call him. He has lost his phone.

Thank you.

Comment: It might be helpful to show the British versions for contrast.

Comment: I certainly would not use the simple past in the first sentence, in American English. In the second sentence, I would need more context to respond.

Comment: The British version would be: I haven't had so much fun for a long time. / You don't need to call him. He has lost his phone.

Comment: We were taught British English at school (by non-native speakers), so I'd always thought that the Present Perfect should be used here. But lately I've noticed it's possible to use either the Simple Past and the Present Perfect in American English in some situations, but I can't figure out when. I wonder why it's possible to say "I didn’t see her for over 20 years and then I bumped into her last week." (from the Cambridge dictionary) but not "I didn't have so much fun for a long time." (though I have to say the use of the Simple Past tense here sounds weird to me too.)

Comment: It's a grammar exercise so it's kind of open to interpretation. He has lost his phone so there's no use calling him. The loss of his phone has an effect on the present so I think the Present Perfect should be used. But then I wonder if it's correct in American English if the Simple Past tense is used.

Comment: @Ana - Thanks Ana, I was suggesting that you show the British examples by editing the question itself. It won't materially change what you are asking and it's easier to compare when the two are side-by-side.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: 'You don't need to call him. He lost / has lost his phone.' sounds infelicitous whichever way you choose to write it. 'There's no point in calling him – he's lost his phone' is idiomatic among Brits.

Comment: How about "there's no point in calling him – he lost his phone". Is this ok in American English?

Comment: Note that the first sentence would be quite natural if you added a word: *I didn't have so much fun **again** for a long time.* (It's a narrative technique.) But without the use of **again** it sounds strange.

Comment: So the simple past tense can be used along with "for a long time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't have so much fun for a long time.

As a native American-English speaker, I would never say this, and if I heard anyone make this statement, I would immediately assume that person was not a native speaker. Instead, I would say something like, "I haven't had that much fun in [or *for*] a long time."

> You don't need to call him. He lost his phone.

This one sounds fine to me. "He lost his phone" indicates a persistent, present situation, even without using the Present Perfect tense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is it wrong to use "so" much there?

Comment: I can't say it would be wrong to use "so" @Ana; it does sound a little more formal to my ears, though.

Comment: Thanks very much, Rob!